# Email Sent to wrong person in SharePoint 2010 Workflow(Same First Name but different domain in email address)

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have SharePoint 2010 designer Workflow and in which i have simple Emal activity.

I have added two user in "To" list in email activity as shown below.

Email Id 1 : samir@test.com.sp(External Email Address)

Email Id 2 : samir@test.onmicrosoft.com(Office 365 email address)

But in that case, email sent twice on "samir@onmicrosoft.com" email address rather than for both user.

Please advice if there is limitation in SharePoint or my mistake.

Comment: Is it working if you are sending if the email recipient is only samir@test.com.sp?

Comment: No, it's not working. Even if i enter that email address in SharePoint Share functionality. It will automatically convert it to Onmicrosoft user.